# How can I use the google voice api on my raspberry pi running debian and chromium

Tags: google-api, debian, raspberry-pi, chromium

I have a raspberry pi running debian and I want to use the google web speech api (https://www.google.com/intl/nl/chrome/demos/speech.html) in chromium. On my windows pc, I get a popup asking if the website can use my microphone but I don't get that on my raspberry pi so it doesn't work. The microphone does work and is connected via a usb audio card.

Can this even be done on a pi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stefan, check out this guide on using the google voice api.  It doesn't use Chromium, but sends recorded voice directly to google's api.

https://harizanov.com/2013/03/siri-like-voice-chat-with-raspberry-pi-keep-kids-busy-for-a-while/